# Array Data send to another php file

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database

Hello every one I have a 2 php files in which I want to send the data through file_put_contents but I want the data to store in this formate `[{"First_Name":"jacob","Last_Name":"caliph"},{"First_Name":"joseph","Last_Name":"jones"},{"First_Name":"Emily","Last_Name":"Joe"}]` in my another php file so please can some one help me to write this format data

Comment: This is JSON format. PHP is capable of using it via [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode) and [json_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Comment: Yes but how I will save it in another php file through file_put_contents

Comment: What do you mean with "save in another php file"? Just write on disk in one script and read back in another. Or even better pass as argument.

Comment: I have wrote this code 

ob_start();
print_r($data);
$textualRepresentation = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

file_put_contents($file, $textualRepresentation); 

But it save my data in the array formate in my another php file but I want it to store in above formate which I have mentioned like the Json formate.

Comment: So...encode it back to JSON again then, as already mentioned.  But it's not clear what you mean by "array format" anyway...if you try to write an array directly to a file in PHP you'll get an error. Did you convert the data to some other format? We can't see the data which ends up in the file so we can't really tell what is happening. The code you've shown looks like it would just read and write the data without changing anything.

Answer (score 0):

In `json.php` you can do this

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json");

//Store the Json Object
$data = array(
  array("First_Name" => "jacob", "Last_Name" => "caliph"),
  array("First_Name" => "jacob", "Last_Name" => "caliph"),
  array("First_Name" => "jacob", "Last_Name" => "caliph"),
  array("First_Name" => "jacob", "Last_Name" => "caliph")
);


//You can the use echo to flush it
//So, when you Request from another php file
//The $data content would be served
$data = json_encode($data);

//First, Erase your Output buffer
//This would eliminate BOMs and other invalid characters
ob_clean();
echo $data;

//Remove $data from memory
unset($data)

//Or: $data = NULL

?>
```